# Getting batch results from OrientDB

Tags: orientdb2.2

Currently, in OrientDB it is possible to batch up commands so that you can run multiple commands at once.   At the moment, it will return the return value of the final command executed (by default).   Is there any way to get it to return a list of the commands, such that each element in the list corresponds to the return value of the sent command?

e.g. I want to send:

```
begin;
insert into class content {"blah": "blah1"};
insert into class content {"blah": "blah2"};
insert into class content {"blah": "blah3"};
commit;
```

and have it return an array with 3 elements, with the first element corresponding to result of inserting blah1, the second blah2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using the batch,you could use the "return", for example:

```
begin
let account = create vertex Account set name = ‘Luke’
let city = select from City where name = ‘London’
let edge = create edge Lives from $account to $city retry 100
commit
return $edge
```

where return ||null -> returns a value instead of last command result (default).

or you could use a javascript function, for example:

```
CLASS PERSON with a property name
CALSS SERVICE with a property field
```

**JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION "myprint"**

```
var g = orient.getGraphNoTx();
g.command('sql', 'INSERT INTO Person CONTENT {"name": "test_F2"}');
g.command('sql', 'INSERT INTO Service CONTENT {"field": "field_F2"}');
var val1= g.command("sql","select from Person where name = 'test_F2'");
var val2= g.command("sql","select from Service where field = 'field_F2'");
var ris="["+val1[0].getRecord().field('@rid')+";"+val1[0].getProperty("name").toString()+"]";
ris=ris + "["+val2[0].getRecord().field('@rid')+";"+val2[0].getProperty("field").toString()+"]";
return ris;
```

**CALL THE FUNCIONT**

select from myprint()

result:
[image]

Comment: What version of OrientDB are you using? I try to run:

begin
let account = create vertex Account set name = ‘Luke’
let city = select from City where name = ‘London’
let edge = create edge Lives from $account to $city retry 100
commit
return $edge
    com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.begin let account = create vertex Account set name = ‘Luke’ let city = select from City where name = ‘London’ let edge = create edge Lives from $account to $city retry 100 commit return $edge DB name="df"

Comment: version 2.2.28 (CE). What is your version?

Comment: version 2.2.30 and 2.2.34 - But ti turns out that you have to switch Studio to batch mode, which makes the above work